# Proof of Max (x,y)

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

The problem states that $ \max(x,y) = \dfrac { x+y+|y-x|} {2} $ where $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$

Part 1) Prove that this is true.

Part 2) Derive a formula for $\max (x,y,z)$.

1) Intuitively i see this as $ \dfrac { x+y} {2} $ as the average between the two numbers ie exactly the middle point between x and y. the order of |y-x| seems arbitrary i would say that |x-y| = |y-x| and that the number after the absolute value illustrates the distance between the lower number up to the larger number. because |y-x| is divided by two we know that we no longer have the distance from the lower number to the top but half way there. so were going from the middle up the distance from the bottom to middle. alternatively if we put a negative sign in we'd be going from the middle down the distance from the bottom to middle. ( ie a min) Beyond intuition this means nothing to me though don't even know were to start.

2) this part seems easy enough to be a trick  $\dfrac { \left( \dfrac { x+y+|y-x|} {2}\right)+z+\left|z-\left( \dfrac { x+y+|y-x|} {2}\right)\right|} {2}$ looks ugly as hell but if my intuition from part 1 was correct this should defiantly work.

Comment: ha.  I like your part 2 answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without Lack of Rigor, assume for instance that $x\gt y$, then $$\max(x,y)\stackrel?=\dfrac{x+y+|y-x|}{2}=\dfrac{x+y-y+x}{2}=x.\,\checkmark$$ So the formula is correct.

For the second question, your result is indeed true since $\max(x,y,z)=\max(\max(x,y),z)$. With some simplifications you'll be left with $$\max(x,y,z)=\dfrac{|y-x|+x+y+2z+\big|\,x+y+|y-x|-2z\,\big|}4.$$

Comment: so obvious once you say this Without Lack of Rigor, assume for instance that x>y

Comment: Do you know, if there is a generalization to this formula, for example you want to have the max of n numbers?

Comment: Just for the sake of symmetry, one could write $\max(x,y,z)$ as $$\frac{1}{12}(4S+\sum_{\text{cyc}}|x-y|+\sum_{\text{cyc}}|S+|x-y|-3z|)$$ with $S=x+y+z$.

Comment: @Imago Yes, there's a [formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PowerMean.html) to find $\max(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n)$ that assumes that $a_k\geqslant0$.

Answer (score 2):

On the numerator of part 1), let's assume x is the max.  Then it becomes $x+y+(x-y)=2x$ and so $\frac{2x}{2}=x$ which is what we assumed as the max.